# If checkbox checked not working in Opencart

Tags: checkbox, opencart

I need to add checkbox to order process in `Opencart 1.5.6.4` and ask `if checkbox is checked`.

I add this checkbox to `template/checkout/confirm.tpl`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test">
```

When I use the condition in `controller/checkout/confirm.php`
`if (isset($_POST['test']))` this condition not working, it is always false even if checkbox is checked.

Is it possible to use another way to create a condition if the checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect input.
must be:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="some_value" />
```